# Radon-Nykodim derivative, Girasanov and the likelihood function

Tags: probability-theory

Assume the stochastic differential equation:

$$dX_t=b(t,X_t)dt+\sigma(t,X_t)dW_t$$

Suppose that for $T>0$, we observe the unique solution $X=(X_t:t\in[0,T])$ of the SDE:

$$dX_t=b(X(t))dt+dW_t,\:\:\:X_0=x_0$$

where W is a brownian motion and b:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R} is an unknown,continuous drift function.
By Girsanov's Theorem, the law that the process X generates on the space $C[0,T]$ of continuous functions on [0,T] is equivalent to the Wiener measure on the space and the corresponding likelihood satisfies:

$$p(X|b)=exp(-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^T b^2(X(t))dt+\int_0^Tb(X_t)dX_t)$$

The versions of the Girsanov theorem that I have studied present me the above likelihood process or the radon-Nykodim derivative as $L(t)$ however I fail to see why $L(t)=p(X|b)$.

L(t) is conditional on the filtration indexed by time but I do not see the reason why it would be a conditional probability on b, the drift.
I have been looking for proofs everywhere of this characterization of the Girsanov likelihood process but found nothing insofar.

**Question**:

Can someone explain me? Or provide a proof?